# gnutls tls client error : a TLS packet with unexpected length was received while reading a url on vlc linux

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

I use Kali linux 64bit and when I type the vlc command with a youtube link as an argument it shows me the error : "gnutls tls client error : a TLS packet with unexpected length was received while reading a url on vlc linux"
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should probably show the command you are using. Or, we need to see a pcap of the session.

Comment: vlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POCngEpkOLI
VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
[0x15960a8] main libvlc : Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'vclc' to use vlc without interface.
[ox19737d8] gnutls tls client error : A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
[ox1957f28] main access error : Read error : Connection reset by peer